# Как избавиться от проблемы, при загрузке проекта выходит следующее. Не удобно каждый раз выбирать

Tags: c#

Как избавиться от проблемы, при загрузке проекта выходит следующее. Не удобно каждый раз выбирать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: после чего это стало происходить?

Comment: Действие "загрузить" не помогает?

Comment: ну а просто галочку поставить, чтобы не открывалось и не спрашивало больше, не? если всё не просто, значит чистить реестр и переустанавливать.

Comment: Попробуйте тупо пересоздать проект. Создайте новый проект, добавьте все файлы из старого.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй воспользоваться советом в ошибке. Установи .net 4.5 или же в свойствах проекта попробуй установить Target Framework более ранней версии.

Тут суть в том, что проект сконфигурирован для работы с .net 4.5, который у тебя просто не установлен.